# Restoring a mnemonic seed with one missing word

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, recovery

I wrote my seed with one missing word (do not know exact position).

Do you know any tool for recovering ethereum wallet? I found this one, bus its for monero. https://github.com/amustafa/recovering-incomplete-monero-mnemonic (this one is for monero)

Next I found this checker. https://zengo-x.github.io/mnemonic-recovery/src/index.html
What do you think about that? Is it clear ?

Or is there any other way how to find one seed word? Checksum?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/jcalfee/bip39-chooser.

Comment: hi friend - has this been solved yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably loop over the list of words(2048) to be exact, which can be found [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/english.txt)

Are you a coder? connect to hdwallet-proivder, with the 11 words you have and the last word will be the word its looping on, and each time you can call web3.eth.getBalance() if you know you had balance of any chain? just so you know this was the right word...

Hope that helps!

Comment: to clarify he doesn't know the exact position of the missing word

Comment: oof, that makes it a challenging task now, rearranging 12 words is a very large number. hmm, I'll be thinking on it

Comment: It is not that hard you have 12 positions, and 2048 words per position so in total 12 * 2048 tries.

Comment: um, you are assuming the known 11 words don't change order between themselves. do we have a confirmation on this whether he knows the the lineup of remaining 11 words to be in correct order? because if not, its 12! * 2048 in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use btcrecover it will help you to find ethereum right pharse but you need Eth address or public key